# Spring form:options tag behaving differently

Tags: java, spring, jsp

in my jsp I list Projects and Home Office states. Projects is a nice drop-down that is collapsed, but Home Office drop-down shows first several entries. Why does Home Office drop-down act differently than Projects? I want it to be collapsed like Projects. getProjects() returns a List of Project objects and getHomeOffice() returns a List of String objects.

```
<p>
    Project: <form:select path="project">
        <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---" />
        <form:options items="${filterBoard.getProjects()}" />
    </form:select>
</p>

<p>
     Home Office: <form:select path="homeOffice">
        <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---" />
        <form:options items="${employee.getHomeOffice()}" />
    </form:select>
</p>
```

[image: List of Home Offices]

Comment: I would totally do a empty cache and hard reload see if still looks different

Comment: Are you sure that there is no multiple="true" attribute in the home office part?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to change the data type of the homeOffice field in my java class from List to String. 
The "project" field that corresponds with `<form:select path="project">` is a String in my java class and filterBoard.getProjects() returns a List. And that works. I had both the "homeOffice" field and employee.getHomeOffice() as Lists. I changed the "homeOffice" field to be a String and renamed my getHomeOffice() method to getHomeOfficeList() and still had it return a List and that fixed it.